# complex polynomial has zeroes only in the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(z)=z^{n}+a_{1}z^{n-1}+...+a_{n}$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients and suppose it has $n$ zeros in the upper half plane, that is $\operatorname{Im} z>0$, and let $\alpha_ {k}$ be the real part of $a_{k}$. Show that $\alpha(x)=x^{n}+\alpha_{1}x^{n-1}+...+\alpha_{n}$ has $n$ real distinct roots.

Comment: I assume $f$ has distinct zeroes for otherwise the statement is false

Comment: @BillO'Haran  observed it in some easy  case,n=1,2,but i found nothing

Comment: Are you able to proceed from my answer?

Comment: @BillO'Haran  thanks for your hint!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @ArtW: It seems that the roots are always distinct.

Comment: @ArtW how the false come?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

Your problem comes down to showing that $P + \overline{P}$ has $n$ real roots. Then write $P = \prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)$ and notice how $|z-z_k|<|z-\overline{z_k}|$ if Im $z>0$.

---

**Whole solution:**

$z$ is a root of $P + \overline{P}$ iff:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)= - \prod_{k=1}^n (z-\overline{z_k})
$$
If Im $z>0$, then:
$$
\forall k\in \{1,\dots,n\}, |z-z_k|<|z-\overline{z_k}|
$$
And:
$$
\left| \prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)\right|< \left|\prod_{k=1}^n (z-\overline{z_k})\right|
$$
Thus, $z$ is not a root of $P+\overline{P}$ and neither is $\overline{z}$ (because $P+\overline{P}$ is a real polynomial).

Comment: +1, great idea! How would you show that the roots are distinct? They are  even if $P(x)=(x-i)^n$ .

Comment: @orangeskid the distinct is another challenge，we need claim that the degree of f is even.

Answer (score 2):

the distinct comes from the following :
Since $$\alpha(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-\alpha_k)$$
$$\alpha'(x)=\alpha(x)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x-\alpha_k}$$